# Run shell scripts as root though Jenkins

Tags: amazon-ec2, jenkins

I have a EC2 instance running. How can I run commands with `sudo` through Jenkins?
When I try `sudo touch /home/ec2-user/foo.bar`, I get the following error: `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A complete guess (I know nothing about Jenkins) - check for `Defaults requiretty` in sudoers (using visudo) and comment it out (probably bad security practise though, but it might help narrow down your problem).

Comment: @cyberex86 I should have mentioned I already did that, that's why I get the error above. Having `requiretty` yields `sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo`.

Comment: Does your user have `NOPASSWD` set (I believe that is the default for Amazon's Linux AMI) and did you set `visiblepw`?

Comment: To bank off @cyberx86, you should be able to run (on the Jenkins box) as `sudo -u jenkins touch /home/ec2-user/foo.bar` without having to enter a password.

Comment: Thanks the both of you! I used the solution by @cyberx86 (I'll accept if you post an answer), in addition I had to create the user `jenkins`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default sudo cannot be used without a TTY. In order to do so:

- Disable 'requiretty' in sudoers (using visudo)

  - This should amount to commenting out 'Defaults requiretty' (using visudo)
- Ensure that your user is able to login without entering a password:

  - Set 'NOPASSWD' in sudoers
  - Create the user if the user does not exist
- Set visiblepw - this will allow sudo to work, even if the password entered is displayed

  - (required in some cases when echo cannot be disabled).

Comment: What do you mean by using visudo?

Comment: @Odelya: visudo is the program used to edit the sudoers file. It is similar to vi(m), however, it performs some checks to catch invalid entries. http://www.sudo.ws/visudo.man.html